# Save already installed Cordova plugins to config.xml

Tags: cordova

I have installed all my cordova plugins using the following syntax:

```
cordova plugin add <plugin-name>
```

I know (now) that if you add the --save flag to your install command, it will add your plugins to config.xml

```
cordova plugin add <plugin-name> --save
```

But, is there a lazy way to automatically add my already installed plugins to config.xml with something like this:

```
cordova plugin save-installed
```

If I am missing something obvious here, don't be shy to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As reported in [this cordova release post](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) from cordova 5 you can add already installed plugins to `config.xml` using just one command:

```
cordova plugin save
```

This will save all previously installed plugins into your project’s `config.xml`.

You can check [the latest `cordova plugin` documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-plugin-command) for more details.

If you need to do the same with the installed platforms, just run [`cordova platform save`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-plugin-command).

Comment: It doesn't work now