# file opener 2 plugin_not_installed error ionic 2 phonegap on android and ios

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, phonegap, fileopener2

**Trying to open pdf from a url in an ionic 2 app**
File opener 2 plugin not working

steps performed: 
1. generated app using :

```
ionic start fileopener blank --v2
```

2.Added file opener:

```
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

3. saved in project

`sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/file-opener`

## home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-home',
 template: ` <ion-content>
               <button ion-button (click)="viewPdf()">Download pdf</button>
              </ion-content> 
             `
})

export class HomePage {

 constructor(private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }

 viewPdf(path) {
   this.fileOpener.open('assets/my.pdf', 'application/pdf')
 .then(() => alert('File is opened'))
 .catch(e =>alert(e));

 }
}
```

## app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   MyApp,
   HomePage
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
 ],
 bootstrap: [IonicApp],
 entryComponents: [
   MyApp,
   HomePage
 ],
 providers: [
   StatusBar,
   SplashScreen,
   FileOpener,
   {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
 ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

## package.json file

```
{
 "name": "ionic-hello-world",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "author": "Ionic Framework",
 "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
   "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
   "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
   "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
   "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
   "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
   "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.0.1",
   "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
   "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
   "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
   "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
   "ionicons": "3.0.0",
   "rxjs": "5.4.0",
   "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
   "zone.js": "0.8.12"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
   "typescript": "2.3.4"
 },
 "cordovaPlugins": [
   "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
   "cordova-plugin-console",
   "cordova-plugin-device",
   "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
   "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
   "cordova-plugin-statusbar"
 ],
 "cordovaPlatforms": [],
 "description": "fileopener: An Ionic project"
}
```

## output of ionic info command

[enter image description here][1]

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.5.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 2.0.2
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v8.1.3
Xcode version: Not installed
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.fileopener585017" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>fileopener</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="~2.0.19" />
</widget>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518646/save-already-installed-cordova-plugins-to-config-xml